# How to get all contrast results after mixed?

Tags: stata, contrast, mixed

How to get all contrast results after mixed?

I used

```
mixed pme i.level2_enc || subject:,mle
```

to conduct a mixed effect model of `pme ~ level2`. Here my `level2` has five categories, `control`, `icon`, `HAS`, `HS`, `SW`. After `mixed`, I tried using

```
contrast ar.level2_enc
```

to get all the comparisons, i.e. `control` vs `SW`, `control` vs `HS`, `HAS` vs `SW`, etc. However, I only get comprisons of following,

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
                   |   Contrast   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------------+------------------------------------------------
pme                |
        level2_enc |
      (HS vs HAS)  |  -.1800729   .0815511     -.3399101   -.0202357
       (SW vs HS)  |   .0470452   .0817447     -.1131715    .2072618
  (control vs SW)  |  -.5816169   .1559947     -.8873608    -.275873
(icon vs control)  |   .6312981   .1560289      .3254871     .937109
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I checked the `help contrast`, and used `contrast r.level2_enc` and `contrast i.level2_enc`, but they did not give me all the comparisons.